# How to restart SQLite auto generated id

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, auto-generate

I have a table with three columns: *Id*, *Value*, *User*. For each user, I want a maximum of 50 values in the table. When a user inserts the value with Id = 50, then before inserting the 51th value, I want to delete the first one (the one with Id=1) and substitute it with the new one, that will have Id=1. This operation must be specific for each user. I use an example to be more clear:

| Id | Value | User |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 124 | User1 |
| 49 | 67 | User2 |
| 50 | 89 | User3 |

Suppose User1 wants to add a new value, the result must be this one:

| Id | Value | User |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 49 | 67 | User2 |
| 50 | 89 | User3 |
| 1 | 101 | User1 |

Of course, Id, Value and User can't be primary keys. So, first of all: is a primary key needed? If not, the problem is easy to solve. Otherwise, I think I will have to add a new column, let's call it *PK*, that will be primaty key and auto generated. From what I read online, if I delete a row, the auto generated key will not restart automatically, so the situation will be more or less like this one:

| PK | Id | Value | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 124 | User1 |
| 2 | 49 | 67 | User2 |
| 3 | 50 | 89 | User3 |

and after the update, will be:

| PK | Id | Value | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 49 | 67 | User2 |
| 3 | 50 | 89 | User3 |
| 4 | 1 | 101 | User1 |

I would like that, when the value 101 is inserted, PK is set to 1, and if User2 adds a new vallue, it is assigned PK=4 (as 2 and 3 are already used)

| PK | Id | Value | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 49 | 67 | User2 |
| 3 | 50 | 89 | User3 |
| 1 | 1 | 101 | User1 |
| 4 | 50 | 33 | User2 |

Is it possible?

I ask it because a new value is inserted more or less every 5 seconds by each user, and the number of users is very high so I am worried that auto generated PK could reach a limit very quickly, if it is not "restarted"

Comment: The max value for an unsigned integer is [4294967295](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html), with (24*60*60/5=) 17280 entries a day, this will last for (4294967295 / 17280 = ) 248551 years.   Hmmm, that really sounds as if you need to start counting again when `50` is reached.....

Comment: If you are consuming values fast, use `UNSIGNED BIGINT`. Still an `INT` will suffice for most cases.

Comment: @Luuk that's not correct: 248551 are not years, but days. This means 681 years for a single user. If I have 1000 users, I will finish numbers in less than 1 year (249 days to be more precise)...

Comment: @TheImpaler how do I set UNSIGNED BIGINT as datatype? I am using *DB Browser for SQLite* to create the db, and I don't see that option...

Comment: "DB Browser for SQLite" That seems to be for using [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html), why did you add the tag [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) to your question. These two databases are (very) different!

Comment: @Luuk you are right...sorry for the mistake

Comment: In SQLite, the [auto increment](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) is stored as a 64-bit signed integer.  My earlier calculations will result in enough years! (Not biting meself twice with a miscalculation.... )